# Error 3706 Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider and Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, visual-foxpro

I made an application that uses VBA in order to read Excel 2013 sheets, and save data in Visual FoxPro tables. This app runs very fine in my computer, but when I run on another computer, issues this error: “Run time error 3706 Provider cannot be found, it may not be properly installed.” I installed, uninstalled, and back to install OLE DB Provider (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro, that comes with VFP SP2)  and VFP runtime files (VFP 9 SP2), but error is issued again. Why does it happen? How can I solve that?

Both computers uses Microsoft Windows 7 Professional SP1 64 bits and Microsoft Office 2013 Professional 32 Bits.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBA and VFPOLEDB, simply use VFP and Microsoft.ACE.Oledb driver to read excel tables. You can check:

[importing exporting excel files sample](https://www.foxite.com/archives/vista-excel-compatibility-w-worksheets-0000153776.htm)